# How do I seperate the .java files in eclipse while exporting to jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javac

Im wondering how do I export a java project to .jar at the same time with a folder that contain all the source files, so I dont mix the class files and  the .java files together.

Comment: i don`t understand your needs, you want to export the sources in the jar?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by Right clicking the Selected Project you want to be exported  `Export --> Jar File` and check the following options.

[image]

and then click finish.